# auto generate username in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to auto-generate username on the basis of first name and last name. For example,
If `firstname = John` and `lastname = Tory` then username should be `johntory`. But, If that username already exist in database the  I want to increment by 1 that means with same name next username will be `johntory2`.

I have something like this in `PHP`..

```
foreach($existing_users as $u){
  if($u['username'] != $new_generated_username){
    // Enter it directly...
  }
  else{
    // increment count value...
  }
}
```

But, there is a problem, if username is like `johntory5` or something...
Is there any way where I can directly update within `INSERT` statement in mysql by checking everything.

This is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e76642/1)

Comment: You should probably base the added number on an auto_incremented id (int) column, and increase it based on that. *Thinking outloud*

Comment: @Fred-ii- : you mean, if username is already there, then I need to contact username with current autoincrement id?

Comment: Exactly, all set inside a conditional statement. That's what I'd do.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : I got the idea. But, 2 things here. I need to update username after insert the query (because I need last_id for username). Secondly, I don't want to publish database ID.

Comment: Depending on the MySQL API you are using, based on `mysqli` you can use `mysqli_num_rows()` or even MySQL's `COUNT()` aggregate function. This stands at being a bit more complicated in querying and applying a `+1` / increment for example to an existing username. Something I could probably figure out by spending some time on, but this could take some time for me. Let's hope someone gets wind of your question and can come up with an actual "answer" as a solution. But basically, that's how I'd do it if I were faced with a similar projet. It just boils down to putting your mind to it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : Alright.. Thanks for your suggestion. I am doing that, the way you explained. It seems easier option.

Comment: You're very much welcome Ronak, *cheers*

Comment: what, if I register `user`, `user1`, `user`(user1 with Count method?)

Comment: @vp_arth The solution to that would be to check if what user enters contains a number using PHP.

Comment: so, you must to disallow numbers in the lastname?

Comment: It reminded me of [this article](http://blog.jgc.org/2010/06/your-last-name-contains-invalid.html) :)

Comment: If somebody wants to register johntory5 and it is taken do you want to suggest johntory6 or johntory51?

Comment: I am not allowing numbers in name field. so, It'll be johntory6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this directly in the INSERT statement like this:

```
 INSERT INTO User (username, first, last) 
 SELECT CONCAT('johntory', COUNT(id)), 'John', 'Tory' 
 FROM User WHERE username LIKE 'johntory%';
```

Or if you don't like the preceding zero, you could use this:

```
 INSERT INTO User (username, first, last) 
 SELECT CONCAT('johntory', CASE WHEN COUNT(id) = 0 THEN '' ELSE COUNT(id) END), 'John', 'Tory' 
 FROM User WHERE username LIKE 'johntory%';
```

This is very fast and efficient. It uses a subquery to prepare the values and then inserts them.

Also, this is going to be many times faster than any of the PHP solutions offered here, especially if you are dealing with billions of rows.

Personally, I love the simplicity and performance of MySql

Enjoy!

~Techdude

Comment: I should also add that for the username itself, you can just convert to lowercase string in php and concatenate when building the query.

Comment: Wow. This one is great solution. That's what I was looking for. Can you please add in you code that how to remove `0` from first entry? Thanks.

Comment: Done! See above for alternative version.

Comment: This is an incorrect solution: What if there is 4 johntory's in your user table. johntory4, johntory1, johntory, and johntory12. You're going to get back johntory4 which already exists.

Comment: This assumes that usernames are consecutive and not deleted. If those two things don't hold, then yes it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Simple approach with a loop in PHP:

```
<?
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","database");

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,'johntory');
$tmp = $username;
$inc = 1;
$valid = false;

// lookup if the username is in use
$qid = mysqli_query($con,"select id from User where username='$username'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($qid) == 0) $valid = true;

// if it is in use, keep looking up until a valid username is found 
while(!$valid) {
    $username = $tmp . $inc; // append number
    $qid = mysqli_query($con,"select id from User where username='$username'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($qid) == 0) $valid = true;
    $inc++;

    //optional
    if($inc>1000) die("Too many John Tory's"); 
}

// insert user
mysqli_query($con,"insert into User(username) values ('$username')");
?>
```

You might want to add an index on username to speed up the queries.

Comment: It's working fine. But the only problem is, there is a `query` in while loop. The performance will be slower on time.

Comment: True. It will be faster if you add an index on username and use prepared statements with PDO. The other answer might be faster, you would have to try. I would use a REGEXP instead of  a LIKE though, to prevent johntory from clashing with johntorydoe. E.g. `where username regexp ':username[0-9]*$'`

Comment: I think @techdude's answer will solve the performance issue. It's checking within the same query. thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a table for user where each row keeps the next suggestion number for that username.

[image]

Then the user register function can look like this:

```
class User {

    private $firstName;
    private $lastName;

    public function __construct($firstName, $lastName) {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
    }

    public function register(Db $db) {
        $username = $this->firstName . $this->lastName;

        $query = "SELECT next_suggestion_id FROM user WHERE username = '$username'";
        $rows = $db->execute($query);

        if (!empty($rows)) {
            //user found, incrementing next suggestion id
            $newSuggestionId = $rows[0]['suggestion_id'] + 1;
            $query = "INSERT INTO user SET suggestion_id = $newSuggestionId"
                      . " WHERE username = '$username'";
            $db->execute($query);

            $username .= $newSuggestionId;
        }

        //inserting user in db
        $query = "INSERT INTO user SET username = '$username' /* other columns */";
        $db->execute($query);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try generating the username with the first and lastname concatenated. Then use the `LIKE`clause in MySql to find any matching usernames. This will generate an array of usernames that is an exact match or like the auto-generated username. You could then loop through this array until you auto generate an username that doesn't exist in the database.

In PHP that would look something like this.

```
// The $suffix is the number to add if the username exists. The default is NULL/nothing
$suffix = null;

// Auto-generate the username.
$username = generate_username_function($firstname, $lastname, $suffix);

// Instantiate a new PDO instance.
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=...', $db_username, $db_password); // Insert your DNS string here.

// Build the SQL query.
$query = "
    SELECT username
    FROM users
    WHERE username LIKE ':username%'
";

$statement = $pdo->prepare($query);

$statement->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);

if(!$statement->execute()) {
    // throw an exception if the query couldn't be executed.
}

$existing = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Loop through the existing usernames to check if the auto-generated username exists.
// Set an $available flag on indicate when the username is available.
$available = false;

$current  = 1;
$ceiling  = 1000; // This is to avoid infinite loops. Increase this if necessary.

while(!$available) {

    // Check if the loop ceiling has been reached.
    if($current == $ceiling) {
        // throw an exception(preferred) or emit an error.
    }

    if(!in_array($username, $existing)) {

        $available = true;

    }else{

        if(is_null($suffix)) {
            $suffix = 1;
        }else{
            $suffix++;
        }

    $username = generate_username_function($firstname, $lastname, $suffix);

    }

    $current++;
}
```

This will continue to increment the suffix until an available username is found. The generation of the username can be improved, but I will leave that to you :D

Now you have an available username and you can store it in the database along with any other information.

Best regards.

Comment: We can't to have infinity database, then no chance to infinity loop, without any restrictions.... (except MAX_INT checking ;) )

Comment: That is correct. I just imagined some crazy situation and decided to be sure. But you are correct my dear sir :D

Comment: Using `LIKE` for this sounds like a bad idea. Just store the actual name of the user in the database and query that instead. Which prevents a slow `LIKE` and prevent dupes which are not dupes. `PeeHaa` / `PeeHaaNotTheSame`.

Comment: If the username that was generated was 'PeeHaaNotTheSame' the `LIKE` clause would return an empty array and the username would be valid. To the `LIKE` clause being slow. That may be correct, but for small systems I would think an index would take the worst overheat.